# CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'culture') 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier

Tags: c#, blazor, globalization

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
```

When using the above code with the `"en-AT"` culture, the below exception occurred. I'm using a Blazor project and I rendered the project default in the en-AT culture.

> Exception : CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
> (Parameter 'culture') 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.

I want to render English (Austria) culture.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-globalization-cultureinfo-ctor(system-int32)) for that constructor recommend to not use LCID here, and instead use the culture name:  `new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);`

Comment: Is en-AT even a thing? Is that what Arnold is speaking?

Comment: It may be that `de-AT` is the only '-AT' culture. See here for how to get a list of available cultures: https://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

Comment: Or do you mean en-AU like in Austr**alia**?

Comment: Was curious, yes `en-AT` [is a valid culture](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=8BjJmx#run-results)

Comment: Ha ... again learned something. Hilarious.

Comment: LCID was deprecated 16 years ago.  It cannot represent custom cultures, like en-AT.  Use the string instead.